# where do I need to start

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to ros and i am building a robot from an old powered wheelchair containing a full PC, two USB high power motor controllers, USB camera on a RC pan and tilt, high power WiFi radio. my goal for this robot for now is remote control over the WiFi.  I have installed ros and have run through most of the beginner tutorials. my question is, where do i start. what are the steps that i need to follow to make it remote controlled. i have no software written for this robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50427/where-do-i-need-to-start/) by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2012-12-14**:
the motor controllers that i am using are simple motor controllers 24v23 from pololu. They do have drivers for linux.

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2012-12-16**:
Ok, I maybe missing something very simple, how do i install gscam and gstreamer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For simple remote control you only need to be able to make your motors move from within a ROS node by sending commands to your motor controllers. I don't know what type of motor controllers you have, but you can ask around to see if a node already exists to talk to them. If no node exists, then you will have to write that yourself.

You can use the [turtlebot_teleop](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_teleop) package to send commands from a joystick or keyboard to your motor controller node. Install that with

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlebot-apps
```

since turtlebot_teleop is a package in the turtlebot_apps stack. Modify that install command to replace `fuerte` if you are using a different version of ROS.

So the order of your nodes will look like the following (with the topics that connect your nodes inside the arrows):

```
turtlebot_teleop_joy (computer 1) --cmd_vel--> motor_controller_node (computer 2) --motor_controller_outputs--> motors
```

Note that you will have to set up your [environment variables](http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/ROS(2f)EnvironmentVariables.html) so that nodes running on two different computers can talk to each other.

To do teleoperation (remote control with cameras) you will have to try out the different camera driver packages (probably [gscam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gscam) since it is USB) to get images out and use [RViz](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz) to view the image stream.

The pan/tilt mechanism would have to be another node, probably one that you write.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2